# Federated Tensorflow memory-overloads a single GPU

Tags: python, tensorflow, out-of-memory, tensorflow-federated

I'm trying to do federated learning using tensorflow.
I've created a model based on [this tutorial for MNIST](https://www.tensorflow.org/federated/tutorials/federated_learning_for_image_classification). Now I change it: I supply it with images of size 112x112 with 3 channels each (I.e. the size of the input layer is 112x112x3). When I try to use multiple models (around 50 with about 100 images each), I get "out of memory" exception. Looking at output of `nvidia-smi`, it makes sense: for some reason my program takes memory only from a single GPU. How can I avoid it?

Some comments:

- I use `allow_growth`, so I'm pretty sure that the shown memory usage is the actual memory usage. And I do can see it growing over time.
- TensorFlow recognizes other GPUs: before I run the program, they have 0MB occupied. Also there is line `Adding visible gpu devices: 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7` in logs.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You have hit an interesting and thorny edge in TFF.

TLDR: TFF uses TF in an unorthodox manner; this hits a bug in TF, in which device placement fails to propagate through `tf.data.Dataset.reduce` correctly, and TFF's ops only get placed on a single GPU.

A TFF contributor is currently working on adding a workaround to TFF's default configuration, which essentially involves more-or-less "tricking" TensorFlow's AutoGraph to generate a `tf.while` loop instead of a dataset reduction. If you are building from source, you can swap the [`dataset.reduce`](https://github.com/tensorflow/federated/blob/master/tensorflow_federated/python/learning/federated_averaging.py#L92) for a specific for-loop:

```py
num_examples_sum = 0
for batch in iter(dataset):
  num_examples_sum = reduce_fn(num_examples_sum, batch)
```

This should cause all the GPUs to be utilized.

If they are still ooming, try adjusting the [`clients_per_thread`](https://www.tensorflow.org/federated/api_docs/python/tff/framework/local_executor_factory?version=nightly) parameter (the inverse of the former `num_client_executors` parameter) upwards; TFF will attempt to run all clients in parallel by default.